Haskell GriWorld Infinite loop
I'm trying to code a GridWorld simulation in Haskell via reinforcement learning. I'm stuck because I keep falling into an infinite loop on line 109. I've been staring at this problem for a week, and I reworked the code from scratch multiple times so I could use some help from someone else's point of view. 
This is output of my program:
Initial Grid:
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 
2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 
3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 
4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 
Training Q-learning agent...
Q-learning training finished.
Final Grid:

Code is executed until line 109 (excluded).
visualizeGrid (\(x, y) -> maximum [finalQTable ((x, y), a) | a <- [minBound .. maxBound]])
Code is compiled fine. In error window (I'm using online enviroment) I got message Main: <<loop>>.
All the code below:
import System.Random
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Control.Monad (foldM)
import Debug.Trace (trace)

type Position = (Int, Int)
type Reward = Float
type GridWorld = Position -> Reward
data Action = Up | Down | MoveLeft | MoveRight deriving (Eq, Enum, Bounded)

instance Show Action where
    show Up = "↑"
    show Down = "↓"
    show MoveLeft = "←"
    show MoveRight = "→"

step :: GridWorld -> Position -> Action -> (Position, Reward)
step world (x, y) action = case action of
    Up       -> ((x, max 0 (y-1)), world (x, max 0 (y-1)))
    Down     -> ((x, min 4 (y+1)), world (x, min 4 (y+1)))
    MoveLeft -> ((max 0 (x-1), y), world (max 0 (x-1), y))
    MoveRight-> ((min 4 (x+1), y), world (min 4 (x+1), y))

type QTable = ((Position, Action) -> Reward)

trainQ :: GridWorld -> QTable -> Float -> Float -> Int -> IO QTable
trainQ world qtable alpha gamma episodes = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    let actions = [minBound .. maxBound] :: [Action]
        positions = [(x, y) | x <- [0..4], y <- [0..4]]
    finalQTable <- snd <$> foldM (\(g, q) _ -> do
                                    let (q', g') = trainEpisode world q alpha gamma actions positions g
                                    return (g', q')) (gen, qtable) [1..episodes]
    return finalQTable

trainEpisode :: GridWorld -> QTable -> Float -> Float -> [Action] -> [Position] -> StdGen -> (QTable, StdGen)
trainEpisode world qtable alpha gamma actions positions gen = 
    let (startPos, newGen) = randomR (0, length positions - 1) gen
        startState = positions !! startPos
        (_, finalQTable, _) = foldl (\(prevPos, q, g) _ -> 
                                        let (newPos, _) = step world prevPos (chooseAction q newPos actions)
                                            (updatedQTable, _) = trainStep world q alpha gamma actions newPos
                                        in (newPos, updatedQTable, g)) 
                                    (startState, qtable, newGen) [1..10]
    in (finalQTable, newGen)

trainStep :: GridWorld -> QTable -> Float -> Float -> [Action] -> Position -> (QTable, Position)
trainStep world qtable alpha gamma actions pos =
    let action = chooseAction qtable pos actions
        (newPos, reward) = step world pos action
        oldValue = qtable (pos, action)
        futureValue = maximum [qtable (newPos, a) | a <- actions]
        newValue = oldValue + alpha * (reward + gamma * futureValue - oldValue)
        qtable' = \s -> if s == (pos, action) then newValue else qtable s
    in (qtable', newPos)

chooseAction :: QTable -> Position -> [Action] -> Action
chooseAction qtable (x, y) actions =
    let validActions = filter (\action -> isValidAction action (x, y)) actions
        bestAction = maximumBy (comparing (\a -> qtable ((x, y), a))) validActions
    in bestAction

isValidAction :: Action -> Position -> Bool
isValidAction Up    (_, y) = y > 0
isValidAction Down  (_, y) = y < 4
isValidAction MoveLeft  (x, _) = x > 0
isValidAction MoveRight (x, _) = x < 4

runAgent :: GridWorld -> QTable -> Position -> [Action] -> IO ()
runAgent world qtable pos actions = do
    putStrLn $ "Current Position: " ++ show pos
    let action = chooseAction qtable pos actions
    putStrLn $ "Chosen Action: " ++ show action
    let (newPos, reward) = step world pos action
    putStrLn $ "Action: " ++ show action ++ ", Reward: " ++ show reward
    if newPos == pos
        then do
            putStrLn "Agent is stuck! Generating random action."
            gen <- newStdGen
            let (randomActionIndex, newGen) = randomR (0, length actions - 1) gen
                randomAction = actions !! randomActionIndex
            putStrLn $ "Random Action: " ++ show randomAction
            let (newPos', reward') = step world pos randomAction
            putStrLn $ "Random Action Result: " ++ show randomAction ++ ", New Position: " ++ show newPos' ++ ", Reward: " ++ show reward'
            runAgent world qtable newPos' actions
        else do
            putStrLn $ "New Position: " ++ show newPos
            runAgent world qtable newPos actions

visualizeGrid :: GridWorld -> IO ()
visualizeGrid world = mapM_ putStrLn [concat [show (round (world (x, y))) ++ " | " | x <- [0..4]] | y <- [0..4]]

gridWorld :: GridWorld
gridWorld (x, y) = fromIntegral (x + y)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Initial Grid:"
    visualizeGrid gridWorld
    putStrLn "Training Q-learning agent..."
    let initialQTable = \_ -> 0.0
        alpha = 0.1
        gamma = 0.9
        episodes = 4
    finalQTable <- trainQ gridWorld initialQTable alpha gamma episodes
    putStrLn "Q-learning training finished."
    putStrLn "Final Grid:"
    visualizeGrid (\(x, y) -> maximum [finalQTable ((x, y), a) | a <- [minBound .. maxBound]])
    putStrLn "Running agent:"
    runAgent gridWorld finalQTable (0, 0) [minBound .. maxBound]


Edit:
On line 42:
let (newPos, _) = step world prevPos (chooseAction q newPos actions)
the newPosin call of chooseAction is supposed to be prevPos. So this line after edit should look like:
let (newPos, _) = step world prevPos (chooseAction q prevPos actions)
However, this does not make the code run properly yet. After this change, I get time out. During my "debugging" attempts, I've been switching basicly between two scenarios: 1) Inifite loop case; and 2) Command timed out case. I assume the origin of the problem has something to do with lazy evaluation, but it is just an assumption. 
My question is simple yet hard: how do I make my code work properly?

The <<loop>> is probably due to this line
let (newPos, _) = step world prevPos (chooseAction q newPos actions)
  -- ^^^^^^                                          ^^^^^^ --

since newPos is recursively defined in terms of itself. Did you mean prevPos in the chooseAction call?

Yes, thank you. The newPos parameter in chooseAction is supposed to be prevPos. Yet after this rework, I get "Command timed out" instead of any output or error. While attempting to make my code work properly, I've been switching between this situation of "time out" and the situation of the infinite loop I described above.
